# How to use blob URL in img tag src?

Tags: javascript, html, blob

I have a generated blob url with the following format :

`blob:file%3A///2aade.....`

I tried to use it directly:

`src="blob:file%.... "`

and tried it with"blob://"  before the url. Which raised a 404 not found error!

what is the correct way to display an image through the blob url?

Comment: Read more about [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: Maybe you could add some code, show us how you've created this blob, and how you're using it as an image source

Comment: Are you sure the blob currently exists in memory? Remember, they only exist on the current page.

Comment: Alon I have been for a while. adeneo it's extracted by zip.js. Reda it's existence wasn't the problem. thank you guys but I figured out what is wrong. I was trying to display the first item in an array of blobs and it happen to be a directory! not even a file. I tried to display the second item and the direct way worked. thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way is:

`src= "blob:file....."`

just set the src to the blob url

My mistake was not making sure it was an image blob in the first place!